# How do I format links in Google's My Maps location descriptions?

Tags: links, formatting, google-my-maps

Google's [My Maps](https://www.google.com/mymaps) supports the placement and customization of locations in its map edition, including the ability to add a "description" to added locations. However I don't see how to format links added to these descriptions. Markdown, for example, does not work:

[image]

Is there a way format links added to Google My Maps location descriptions?